# Every semisimple Lie algebra of dimension at most 5 is simple.

Tags: lie-algebras

How does one argue that every semisimple Lie algebra of dimension $\leq 5$ is simple. Since any simple algebra has dimension at least $3$, we have to show that any semisimple algebra of dimension $3,4,5$ is simple.

Comment: There is no semisimple Lie algebra in dimension $4$ or $5$ over a field of characteristic zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be semisimple, then $\mathfrak{g}=\oplus_{i=1}^n\mathfrak{g}_i,$ where each $\mathfrak{g}_i$ is simple. The dimension of every $\mathfrak{g}_i$ is $\geq3$. If the dimension of $\mathfrak{g}$ is $\leq5$, how many $\mathfrak{g}_i$'s can there be?

Comment: I somehow had at first not the characterization of direct sum of simple algebras in mind while thinking about it...

Answer (score 2):

In characteristic $p>0$ a semisimple Lie algebra $L$ need not be the direct sum of simple Lie algebras, and there are simple Lie algebras not only of  dimension $3$, but also of dimension $5$, i.e., the $p$-dimensional Witt algebra $W(1,1)$ for $p=5$. Probably it is still true that every semisimple Lie algebra of dimension $n\le 5$ is already simple, but I did not find this yet in the literature.

In characteristic zero, every semisimple Lie algebra is the direct sum of simple Lie algebras, which have at least dimension $3$, because every Lie algebra of dimension $n\le 2$ is solvable. Hence there is no semisimple Lie algebra of dimension $4$ and $5$, and it remains to show that every semisimple Lie algebra of dimension $3$ is simple. So let $L$ be semisimple, and $\dim(L)=3$. Let $I$ be a proper ideal of $L$. Then $I$ and $L/I$ are solvable, because both are of dimension at most $2$. Hence $L$ is solvable, a contradiction. Hence $L$ has no proper ideal, and is simple.

Comment: In char 0, why cant a Lie Alg dim 4 or 5 be simple?

Comment: @mdave16 See solution hint [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=19&ved=0ahUKEwi8rMTf8vvTAhVD_ywKHXaWBDc4ChAWCGQwCA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhome.aubg.edu%2Ffaculty%2Ftatyana%2FLie%2520AlgebrasMAT497%2FLieAlg_Spr13_Q6.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHaJ0VdE1Ntxnn5M-Fq1IKBuma0Jg&sig2=xo7esIyByqPcZ23zHvPGow), i.e., use that $\dim L=\dim H+|\Phi|$.